# Is it possible to output the name of a Matrix Block?

Tags: matrix, custom-field, blocks, filter, block-types

I'd like to output the Names of Matrix Blocks. I know you can [filter by block types](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields#filtering-by-block-type) e.g.

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField.type('text, heading') %}
{% if block.type == "heading" %}
    <h3>{{ block.heading }}</h3>
{% else %}
    {{ block.text | markdown }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know I could use `{{ block.type }}` and get the block type's handle but, I want to included the actual *Name* of the block type itself too.

For example, something like this:

```
{{ block.type.name }}
```

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`block.type` is actually an alias for a `getType()` function, which returns a new *MatrixBlockTypeModel* object. Those will output their handle by default, which is why it's possible to compare `block.type`  against block type handles. But MatrixBlockTypeModel also has a `handle` property, so this is totally possible:

```
{{ block.type.handle }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this means that using:

`{% if block.type in ['video', 'image', 'gallery'] %}`

…does not seem to work, [as per this example](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2910/4208).

Is there another way? Using `in` is very tidy!

Comment: @ianp You need `.name` after `block.type`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and no joy.

Just to be clear, `( block.type == 'video' or block.type == 'image' or block.type == 'gallery' )` does still work, however.

Comment: Sorry I should have said `.handle`

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear to be in the matrix block model. http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/matrixblockmodel