# Multiple conditions in an if statement?

Tags: templating

Is it not possible to define multiple conditions in an if statement?

```
{% if foo == 'x' || foo == 'y' %}
```

I tried this and got an error:

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "|" ("name" expected)

Comment: Thanks, all!  I had originally tried "AND" but it did not work.  Does in lowercase!!

Answer (score 21):

Twig doesn't accept `||` or `&&`... Try using `or` and `and` instead.

```
{% if foo == 'x' or foo == 'y' %}
```

Important to note, **they must be lowercase**.

You may also want to take a look at [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2882/45), which shows another way to write a similar condition:

```
{% if foo in ['x', 'y'] %}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the "They must be lowercase" note. I wondered why I couldn't get such a simple bit of logic working :)